# How to add attribute to DynamoDB table without scan?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, ttl

I have recently introduced TTL feature in AWS DynamoDB table, Now newly added record will expire after certain time and using DynamoDB Stream Lambda will be invoked and will push "removed" data to another archive DynamoDB table.

Now, as the old data do not have ttl attribute , How can I add this to older items (except some), I know we can use scan , but the bottle neck here is performance of it I have close to 400K items and no index, I do not want to scan whole table.

Is there any efficient way to achieve this ?
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated , Thanks.

Comment: How do you intend to identify the items that need TTL?

Comment: There could be various approach for this , Lets say the item which does not have ttl already or based on certain other attributes.

Comment: If you have arbitrary requirements then I don't see what option you have but to scan the table, identify the items, and then update those that need TTL (perhaps in a batched update). How otherwise would you expect to do this?

Comment: Thanks for update , Actually that is what I am exploring , if that can be achieved or not .

Comment: You could export the table to S3, Run a Glue Crawler on it and Query it with Athena to find the items that need the TTL and then write a script to actually update the items. Or you bite the bullet, scan the table and just update the items, I'm with @jarmod on this.